# accessing sleeping threads resources

Tags: java

is it safe for the thread from start_thread, to access packetList while the start_activity thread(main thread) is sleeping on a semaphore. If not then how can I share the resource between them, please note the access will only be read and the packetList wont be changed.

```
            class A{
                Vector<packet> packetList;
                A()
                {
                    //packetList initialized here
                }

                void start_thread()
                {
                //start a thread here
                }
                void start_activity()
                {
                    while(true)
                    {
                        //possibly sleep on semephore
                        //do work
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: It is possible, but you must synchronize access to the list. You must think about the case when somebody reads the vector just as the thread is waking.

Comment: @JakubZaverka can the other thread access the array while the main thread is sleeping on a semaphore ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the Vector, provided you don't iterate over it.  If you Iterate over it, you need to hold a lock with `synchronized` on that object.

If you want to queue "packets" of work, I suggest you look at using a BlockingQueue where you can wait for new tasks to be added, or use an ExecutorService which combines a Queue with a ThreadPool.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your question is a rephrasing of "I am using a semaphore to synchronise thread access to a shared data structure" - in which case the answer is "definitely yes", provided your access to the  Vector is exactly as stated, ie:

```
while(true)
    {
        //acquire lock
        //do work
        //release lock
    }
```

and you have a matching structure on the main thread (ie you acquire the lock before doing any work) - this will assure threads' access to the Vector is properly synchronised

Comment: Basically, I want to have on demand access to the array from both threads regardless of which one is sleeping, how can I do that?